# Collecting Yarn Metrics

Tags: yarnpkg

I would like to collect metrics on how long `yarn` commands such as `yarn install` take to complete and other metrics such as how often the commands don't complete successfully.

My `.yarnrc` file looks like this:

```
registry "https://artifactory-content.company.build/artifactory/api/npm/npm"
"--ignore-engines" true
"@sail:registry" "https://artifactory-content.company.build/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local"
"@company-internal:registry" "https://artifactory-content.company.build/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local"
lastUpdateCheck 1617811239383
yarn-path "./yarn-1.19.1.js"
```

From what I understand, when I run the `yarn` command, it invokes the `yarn-1.19.1.js` file. Would it be possible to create a wrapper such that when any yarn command is run, it logs the metrics at the command level and then executes the `yarn-1.19.1.js` file?

Another approach I ran across was modifying the `package.json` file and overriding the commands as mentioned [here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run) but this doesn't seem scalable as there might be new commands added later on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create a wrapper script that invokes the Yarn core library.  This is exactly what the Node.js that is `yarn` does:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

var ver = process.versions.node;
var majorVer = parseInt(ver.split('.')[0], 10);

if (majorVer < 4) {
  console.error('Node version ' + ver + ' is not supported, please use Node.js 4.0 or higher.');
  process.exit(1);
} else {
  try {
    require(__dirname + '/../lib/v8-compile-cache.js');
  } catch (err) {
  }

  var cli = require(__dirname + '/../lib/cli');
  if (!cli.autoRun) {
    cli.default().catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error.stack || error.message || error);
      process.exitCode = 1;
    });
  }
}
```

You could just edit that script like so:

```js
  const start = Date.now();

  var cli = require(__dirname + '/../lib/cli');
  if (!cli.autoRun) {
    cli.default()
      .then(function() {
        const durationInMs = Date.now() - start;
        // It succeeded, do your stuff.
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error.stack || error.message || error);
        process.exitCode = 1;
        
        const durationInMs = Date.now() - start;
        // It failed, do your stuff.
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Some more noob questions: How would I hook this script into the `yarn` command itself, so whenever someone runs `yarn` it executes this new script?

Comment: If you take script that is run when you run `yarn` in a terminal (find it by running `where yarn`), and edit it as I've done above, the modifications will be run every time you run `yarn`.  If you want your custom code to run every time you or anyone runs `yarn` no matter on what device, you'll need to automate the patching of that script, which would be very simple to do.